# EntityReference has an EntityKey property value that does not match the EntityKey for this object

Tags: entity-framework

I want to add the user in `Users` table with Entity Framework.

I added all the references viz.

```
this.UserRolesReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("KEntities.UserRoles", "UserRoles", roleID);

this.OfficeMasterReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("KEntities.OfficeMaster", "SROCode", SROCode);

this.UserDesignationsReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("KEntities.UserDesignations", "UserDesignations", designationId);
```

When I do this

```
context.AddObject(this.GetType().Name.ToString(), this);[ this is object of Users]
```

it gives me an error

> The object could not be added or attached because its EntityReference has an EntityKey property value that does not match the EntityKey for this object.

The `Users` table has only relationship with `UserRoles` , `UserDesignations` and `OfficeMaster`

Still in the `KModel.edmx` file under `Users` table in the Navigation Properties it shows `CustomPermissions`, `UserLog`

`CustomPermissions` and `UserLog` have an association with `Users` but I am not inserting any values into them.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you need to modify EntityKey, I think we should not reference or modify it directly, we should only access our classes and properties and let EF manage everything.

Comment: @akash thanks for reply, if i am inserting record in users table the roleID field is not present in users(generated class) , to insert role_id i must modify entity key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Entity Framework, you are not supposed to change or set RoleID manually, instead you must set the navigation property and RoleID will be correctly updated.

```
Role adminRole = GetTheAdminRole(); // get instance of Role

User newUser =new User();

context.Users.Add(newUser);
newUser.Role = adminRole;

context.SaveChanges();
```